# How to deploy a web site on IIS by using .dll file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to deploy on IIS my web site but I do not want to take whole project. I just need to take `.dll` file. Is their any way to do so.

I do not want to use visual studio only `.dll` file from the project to deploy.

Answer (score 4):

The basic steps for deploying to IIS on windows server are as follows:

1. log onto the machine that is or will be hosting your application.
2. Use IIS Manager to create a new website for your application.
3. Create a new application in that site. I believe this also will automatically create an application pool with the same name for you and use it by default.

   Specify the virtual directory for your application. This is going to tell IIS where to look for your mvc application. For this case lets assume it is C:\myApp

   On your own machine Build the application however you build it with the correct solution configuration (i.e. Release mode). Let say the result of your build is located at C:\MyProject\bin

   Copy C:\MyProject\bin from your machine onto your hosting machine at C:\myApp

You should be able to search these steps and find a step by step guide of how to accomplish them. Here is a link to some info on what sites, applications and app pools are to help you better understand. 
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Based on your sites requirements there will be some additional steps to set up security and alter bindings if you need to change them.

Comment: thanks mmilleruva, i follows the steps but when i browse, it shows only       dll file,not the web page.

Comment: I am beginner to these things.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to deploy your entire website if you only make a change in a single assembly. You could copy the .DLL assembly directly to the `bin` folder of your website. This will trigger the Application Pool to be recycled in IIS and the changes will be taken into effect on the next request.

Comment: but i don't know how to deploy without using visual studio. is their any tutorial to do so.